# webstart application logging permission denied

Tags: java, logging, java-web-start

is it possible to use java.util.Logging and log to a file in a java webstart application?
I have the following logging code:

```
 Handler fh = new FileHandler("myapp.log");
 Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName()).addHandler(fh);
```

and got the following exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Handler.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.(Unknown Source)
    at whoisapiclient.WhoisAPIClientApp.main(WhoisAPIClientApp.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access control exception says this:

> "access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)"

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LoggingPermission.html) for the permission class says this:

> *"Currently there is only one named LoggingPermission. This is "control" and it grants the ability to control the logging configuration, for example by adding or removing Handlers, by adding or removing Filters, or by changing logging levels.*"

What you are doing clearly falls under the "control" permission.

You will need to sign your application if it is to create/add its own log handlers.

---

Incidentally, if you did manage to work around the `LoggingPermission("control")`, you would then run into another access issue in opening the log file.

Both problems are solved by signing the application.  You've then got the problem that the user has to accept / trust your signing key.  But that is fair enough!  As far as the Java security sandbox can tell, what you are doing could potentially damage the user's machine.

Comment: After I sign all the application jars, it works now!  now where can I find the logging and other files that application wrote to the working dir?  where is the working dir?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.  I'm not even sure it is predictable.  Try doing a file name search.  Alternatively see what `new File("myapp.log").getAbsolutePath()` gives you when you run it on the JWS platform.

Comment: I self-signed my jar but still having same problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213521/how-can-i-force-java-web-start-to-run-a-self-signed-jnlp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying an absolute path?  Perhaps the issue is that you don't have access to the current working directory of the application itself.

Comment: is there a portable way of specifying current work directory?  what's a sensible working directory for a webstart application?  where should I put the log files in?

Comment: @Shawn D. - this is not the actual problem.  (But it would be a problem if the application got to the point where the file handler tried to open the file ...)